# DocuSign createEnvelope Request Failed with 404 Error

Tags: node.js, docusignapi

I have been trying to create an envelope from a template using the Docusign SDK in Node.js, but no matter what API I try run, I get the error 404, with this Html code as a response.

I am including the code here:

```
const {email, name, templateId} = body;
const token = await DocuSign.token();
const dsAPIClient = new ApiClient();
dsAPIClient.setBasePath(DOCUSIGN_BASE_PATH as string);
dsAPIClient.addDefaultHeader('Authorization', `Bearer ${token}`);
const envelopeApi = new docusign.EnvelopesApi(dsAPIClient);
const envelope = this.makeEnvelope({email, name, templateId});
console.log(envelope);
// const result = await envelopeApi.createEnvelope(ACCOUNT_ID as string, {
//   envelopeDefinition: {},
// });
const result = await axios.post(
  `${DOCUSIGN_BASE_PATH}/v2.1/accounts/${ACCOUNT_ID}/envelopes`,
  envelope,
  {
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
    },
  }
);
// console.log('This is the result', result);
return result.data;
```

This is the error that I am getting, I get the same error on SDK and Axios both.

```
Symbol(kOutHeaders)]: [Object: null prototype]
    '  <h2>404 - File or directory not found.</h2>\r\n' +
    '  <h3>The resource you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.</h3>\r\n' +
    ' </fieldset></div>\r\n' +
    '</div>\r\n' +
    '</body>\r\n' +
    '</html>\r\n'
},
isAxiosError: true,
toJSON: [Function: toJSON]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code has the SDK code commented, so I'm not sure why you did this.
Here is code that works, you can find it in G[itHub](https://github.com/docusign/code-examples-node/blob/master/embeddedSigning.js).
An even easier option is to use the [quickstart](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/quickstart/).

```
 let dsApiClient = new docusign.ApiClient();
  dsApiClient.setBasePath(args.basePath);
  dsApiClient.addDefaultHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + args.accessToken);
  let envelopesApi = new docusign.EnvelopesApi(dsApiClient),
    results = null;

  let envelope = makeEnvelope(args.envelopeArgs);

function makeEnvelope(args) {
  let docPdfBytes;
  docPdfBytes = fs.readFileSync(args.docFile);

  let env = new docusign.EnvelopeDefinition();
  env.emailSubject = "Please sign this document";

  let doc1 = new docusign.Document(),
    doc1b64 = Buffer.from(docPdfBytes).toString("base64");
  doc1.documentBase64 = doc1b64;
  doc1.name = "Lorem Ipsum"; // can be different from actual file name
  doc1.fileExtension = "pdf";
  doc1.documentId = "3";

  env.documents = [doc1];

email
  let signer1 = docusign.Signer.constructFromObject({
    email: args.signerEmail,
    name: args.signerName,
    clientUserId: args.signerClientId,
    recipientId: 1,
  });

  let signHere1 = docusign.SignHere.constructFromObject({
    anchorString: "/sn1/",
    anchorYOffset: "10",
    anchorUnits: "pixels",
    anchorXOffset: "20",
  });
  let signer1Tabs = docusign.Tabs.constructFromObject({
    signHereTabs: [signHere1],
  });
  signer1.tabs = signer1Tabs;

  let recipients = docusign.Recipients.constructFromObject({
    signers: [signer1],
  });
  env.recipients = recipients;

  env.status = "sent";

  return env;
}
```